# how can i change noCancelOnOutsideClick of paper-toast?

Tags: polymer

i tried the below code it's not working

```
    <paper-toast class$="center cursor-d horizontal justified layout" duration="4000" id="toast" no-cancel-on-outside-click="false" on-iron-announce="toast_open" on-transitionend="transition">
  <div class="cursor-p self-start" hidden="[[!undo]]" on-click="clear_undo">UNDO</div>
</paper-toast>
```

but

```
document.querySelector("#toast").noCancelOnOutsideClick = false
```

is working when i try it from console

what is correct html syntax to assign false ? pls help

Comment: no-cancel-on-outside-click="false" is not working

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bit tricky. `noCancelOnOutsideClick` is a Boolean attribute. Normally, any presence in the HTML will set it to `true`, inlcluding `no-cancel-on-outside-click="false"`. 
If you want to set it to `false` you would just leave it away in your HTML.

So to set the value to `true`, you would do this:

```
<paper-toast no-cancel-on-outside-click>
```

And for `false` this:

```
<paper-toast>
```

**However** the attribute defaults to `true`, so the above does not work.
You could either set the attribute in the `ready` function like you do now in the console or use data-binding.

```
<paper-toast no-cancel-on-outside-click$=[[myFalseValue]]>
```

There's an interesting discussion on Boolean attributes in Polymer on [Github](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1812).

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that the attribute defaults to `true`. I'm just trying to figure out the easiest way to solve this...

Comment: Is you code part of a custom element? If yes, you could set it programmatically, for example in the `ready` function.